# gradlew.bat failed,unable to open jvm

Tags: jvm, nativescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDVSv.png)
I'm new to nativescript and while running the app i'm getting this error of

> Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1. 
>   can not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>
> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx16384M
>   The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

i've tried removing android platform and then adding it again but still no any good result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are using 32bit JVM? You might have to setup 64bit one. More details about the issue can be found at [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/758)

Comment: no,i've checked i'm using 64bit and also i've changed org.gradle.jvmargs to 2048M but still the error is same .Is there a way to make our project size less ?or recommend me some other solution.

Comment: Do you have multiple JVM on your machine? Can you confirm how did you verify yours on 64bit? Is the 64bit JVM path set on JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I previously had jdk 10 but then as per requirement of nativescript I downloaded jdk 8 and set its path in env variable.I searched for the solution on internet to check 64 bit and so I've  6bits in my jdk version 1.8.0_242. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What does `java –version` return exactly?

Comment: Would you mind confirming what was the issue / how you fixed it?

Comment: yeah the issue was of heap size so I changed the heap size to (org.gradle.Jvmargs=-Xmx =512m ) in gradle/ gradle.properties and also in settings->controlPanel->Programs->Java  and set runtime parameter to -Xmx512m.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But I wonder if it's 64bit it should have supported > 2gb for heap.

Comment: well i'm not getting this error now but a new error that "device is not authorized. " I used to run apps on mobile while working with android studio and they worked perfectly but getting this authorization issue in nativescript.Suggest me a solution of this.

Comment: I had the exact same problem after spending few hours of troubleshooting I found that my JAVA_HOME is set with 64 bit version of JDK but my Intellij IDE was configured to use 32 bit version of JDK. I updated my IDE SDK with 64 bit version JDK to fix the issue.